# what will be the time complexity of the following recurrence relation T(n) = n*T(n-1)

Tags: recurrence

T(1) = 1 and
T(n) = n*T(n-1) when n > 1

Find out the time complexity of the recurrence relation.

After trying out the question my answer is coming out to O(n!).
T(n-1) = (n-1) * T(n-2)
substituting it in the T(n)
T(n) = n * (n-1) * (n-2)
.
.
.
after k times
T(n) = n * (n-1) * (n-2)...... * T(1)
T(n) = O(n!)

Please tell if it is correct or not!

Comment: It is correct! You could take your reasoning and use a proof by induction if you want a formal proof.